# Can We Create a Gizmos Like cone in unity with script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a cone Gizmo like the one in the picture below by using a script.

#### This is an example code:

```
void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, range);
}
```

The red line is the Gizmo that I want.
[image: gizmos]

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 2):

The code below is a modified version of Tetrad's answer to a [similar question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/21176/gizmo-question-how-do-i-create-a-field-of-view-usi.html).

```
void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    float angle = 30.0f;
    float rayRange = 10.0f;
    float halfFOV = angle / 2.0f;
    float coneDirection = 180;

    Quaternion upRayRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-halfFOV + coneDirection, Vector3.forward);
    Quaternion downRayRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(halfFOV + coneDirection, Vector3.forward);

    Vector3 upRayDirection = upRayRotation * transform.right * rayRange;
    Vector3 downRayDirection = downRayRotation * transform.right * rayRange;

    Gizmos.DrawRay(transform.position, upRayDirection);
    Gizmos.DrawRay(transform.position, downRayDirection);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + downRayDirection, transform.position + upRayDirection);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: hey mate thanks but this happend, i want like picture in 2d ( 3d gizmos wasnt right as well), here is pics :  https://prnt.sc/kpnn1f             https://prnt.sc/kpnn3c

Comment: Sorry, I edited the above code to work for the 2D example in your question. You can adjust the cone's direction with the coneDirection variable.